# What are the power subgroups of free groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $F_n$ be a free group of rank $n$. For a fixed $k$, consider the subgroup $P_{n,k}$ generated by $k$th powers of elements of $F_n$. This is a characteristic subgroup. What are the quotients $F_n/P_{n,k}$?

I would guess that it's just $C_k^n$ (direct product of $n$ copies of the cyclic group of order $k$), but I'm not sure.

Comment: ... "*free Burnside groups*" is the magic phrase. Deep mathematic is involved regarding these groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotient of $F_n$ by the normal subgroup $F_n^k$ generated by all $k$-th powers of elements of $F_n$ is defined to be the *free Burnside group $B_n(k)$ of rank $n$ and exponent $k$*. In $1902$, W. Burnside asked whether or not $B_n(k)$ has to be finite. This turned out to be a very hard problem, and it is true for some small exponents $k=2,3,4,6$, but not true in general. These groups are infinite in general. In particular, such groups are not the direct product of $n$ copies of $C_k$ in general (but it is true for $k\le 2$).

Comment: Do you know of any special results in the case $n = 2$? For example, are the quotients finite in this case? Do they have finite rank as free groups?

Comment: $k=1$: cyclic group, $k=2$: Klein four group, $k=3$: elementary abelian group of order 8, $k=4$: elementary abelian group of order 16 ...

Comment: ... what do you mean "finite rank as free groups"?

Comment: Already for $n=2$, and for any odd period $k ≥ 4381$ the free Burnside group $B(2,k)$ is infinite. For more results see [this thesis](http://digitalcommons.liberty.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1605&context=honors) for example.

Comment: @M.U. These burnside groups are subgroups of $F_n$, and hence are free. So I'm asking about their rank.

Comment: That is wrong!! Free Burnside groups are **quotients** of free groups not subgroups.

Comment: @M.U You seem to have mixed up rank and exponent in some of your examples.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Whups. You are absolutely right :)